# Fastest way to split a Stream according to a pattern

Tags: c#

What would be the most optimal/fastest way to split a Steam into chunks delimited by a byte pattern (eg. `new byte[] { 0, 0 }`)?

My current, naieve and slow, implementation reads the stream byte per byte, decrements a counter each time it encounters the delimiter. If the counter is zero, it yields a memory chunk.

```
const int NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE_DELIMITER = 2;
const int DELIMITER = 0;

public IEnumerable<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> Chunk(Stream stream)
{
    var chunk = new MemoryStream();

    try
    {
        int b; //the byte being read
        int c = NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE_DELIMITER;

        while ((b = stream.ReadByte()) != -1) //Read the stream byte by byte, -1 = end of the stream
        {
            chunk.WriteByte((byte)b); //Write this byte to the next chunk

            if (b == DELIMITER) 
                c--; //if we hit the delimiter (ie '0') decrement the counter
            else
                c = NUMBER_CONSECUTIVE_DELIMITER; //else, reset the couter

            if ((c <= 0 || stream.Position == stream.Length) //we hit two subsequent '0's
            {
                var r = chunk.ToArray().AsMemory(); //parse it to a Memory<T>

                chunk.Dispose();
                chunk = new();

                yield return r;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        chunk.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of ReadByte/WriteByte you could introduce a buffer and call Read/Write. You would search for delimiter in the buffer and properly handle the case when consecutive delimiters are split between buffers. And also the case when there are several delimiters in the same buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually ended up with the below code, strongly inspired by Philipp's answer above and https://keestalkstech.com/2010/11/seek-position-of-a-string-in-a-file-or-filestream/.

```
public override IEnumerable<byte[]> Chunk(Stream stream)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    var size = bufferSize;
    var offset = 0;
    var position = stream.Position;
    var nextChunk = Array.Empty<byte>();

    while (true)
    {
        var bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, offset, size);

        // when no bytes are read -- the string could not be found
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            break;

        // when less then size bytes are read, we need to slice the buffer to prevent reading of "previous" bytes
        ReadOnlySpan<byte> ro = buffer;
        if (bytesRead < size)
            ro = ro.Slice(0, offset + bytesRead);

        // check if we can find our search bytes in the buffer
        var i = ro.IndexOf(Delimiter);
        if (i > -1 &&  // we found something
            i <= bytesRead &&  //i <= r  -- we found something in the area that was read (at the end of the buffer, the last values are not overwritten). i = r if the delimiter is at the end of the buffer
            nextChunk.Length + (i + Delimiter.Length - offset) >= MinChunkSize)  //the size of the chunk that will be made is large enough
        {
            var chunk = buffer[offset..(i + Delimiter.Length)];
            yield return new byte[](Concat(nextChunk, chunk));

            nextChunk = Array.Empty<byte>();

            offset = 0;
            size = bufferSize;
            position += i + Delimiter.Length;
            stream.Position = position;
            continue;
        }
        else if (stream.Position == stream.Length)
        {
            // we re at the end of the stream
            var chunk = buffer[offset..(bytesRead + offset)]; //return the bytes read
            yield return new byte[](Concat(nextChunk, chunk));

            break;
        }

        // the stream is not finished. Copy the last 2 bytes to the beginning of the buffer and set the offset to fill the buffer as of byte 3
        nextChunk = Concat(nextChunk, buffer[offset..buffer.Length]);

        offset = Delimiter.Length;
        size = bufferSize - offset;
        Array.Copy(buffer, buffer.Length - offset, buffer, 0, offset);
        position += bufferSize - offset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Such an implementation is extremely difficult to implement because a stream has to be read out in fixed buffer sizes. The buffer can be too big or too small for the content to be interpreted. To solve this problem, the `ReadOnlySequence<T>` struct was added. More information about this topic can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/pipelines).

By using `System.IO.Pipelines` (package must be obtained) this problem can be solved as follows:

```
public static async Task FillPipeAsync(Stream stream, PipeWriter writer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // The minimum buffer size that is used for the current buffer segment.
    const int bufferSize = 65536;

    while (true)
    {
        // Request 65536 bytes from the PipeWriter.
        Memory<byte> memory = writer.GetMemory(bufferSize);

        // Read the content from the stream.
        int bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(memory, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (bytesRead == 0) break;

        // Tell the writer how many bytes are read.
        writer.Advance(bytesRead);

        // Flush the data to the PipeWriter.
        FlushResult result = await writer.FlushAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (result.IsCompleted) break;
    }

    // This enables our reading process to be notified that no more new data is coming.
    await writer.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This will read your stream asynchronously and write a buffer segment to the pipe. Next you have to implement a read logic to slice/merge the concatenated buffer segments into chunks:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<ReadOnlySequence<byte>> ReadPipeAsync(PipeReader reader, ReadOnlyMemory<byte> delimiter,
    [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Read from the PipeReader.
        ReadResult result = await reader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer = result.Buffer;

        while (TryReadChunk(ref buffer, delimiter.Span, out ReadOnlySequence<byte> chunk))
            yield return chunk;

        // Tell the PipeReader how many bytes are read.
        // This is essential because the Pipe will release last used buffer segments that are not longer in use.
        reader.AdvanceTo(buffer.Start, buffer.End);

        // Take care of the complete notification and return the last buffer. UPDATE: Corrected issue 2/.
        if (result.IsCompleted)
        {
            yield return buffer;
            break;
        }
    }

    await reader.CompleteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static bool TryReadChunk(ref ReadOnlySequence<byte> buffer, ReadOnlySpan<byte> delimiter,
    out ReadOnlySequence<byte> chunk)
{
    // Search the buffer for the first byte of the delimiter.
    SequencePosition? position = buffer.PositionOf(delimiter[0]);

    // If no occurence was found or the next bytes of the data in the buffer does not match the delimiter, return false.
    // UPDATE: Corrected issue 3/.
    if (position is null || !buffer.Slice(position.Value, delimiter.Length).FirstSpan.StartsWith(delimiter))
    {
        chunk = default;
        return false;
    }

    // Return the calculated chunk and update the buffer to cut the start.
    chunk = buffer.Slice(0, position.Value);
    buffer = buffer.Slice(buffer.GetPosition(delimiter.Length, position.Value));
    return true;
}
```

For this to work in that form you have to use an `IAsyncEnumerable` so that the chunks can be streamed into a foreach loop. Merging and slicing is largely handled by the pipe, so that a reliable algorithm can be built here with relatively little code. This code will also handle this in a high-performance manner.

**Usage**:

```
// Create a Pipe that manages the buffer.
Pipe pipe = new Pipe();
ConfiguredTaskAwaitable writing = FillPipeAsync(stream, pipe.Writer).ConfigureAwait(false);

// The delimiter that should be used. This can be any data with length > 0.
ReadOnlyMemory<byte> delimiter = new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(new byte[] { 0, 0 });

// 'await foreach' and 'await writing' are executed asynchronously (in parallel).
await foreach (ReadOnlySequence<byte> chunk in ReadPipeAsync(pipe.Reader, delimiter))
{
    // Use "chunk" to retrieve your chunked content.
};

await writing;
```

Note that reading and chunking is done asynchronously and independently.

Comment: Philipp, this answer is amazing - Im working through some of the edge cases and will be sharing an updated snippet soon.

Comment: Philipp, there were some quirks in your answer that I could not iron out to my liking which may have been implicit requirements on my side: 1/ there is a hard break at 65k bytes (the reader.Buffer) which is not desirable, 2/ the 'last' chunk was lost (ie the part after the last '00') 3/ it accidentally also sliced on '0' (but that was a small typo to correct).

Comment: @WouterVanRanst I've fixed the mentioned issues and included some documentation to make it clear. To answer 1/: The hard break could be an artifact of your underlying stream. E.g. the Socket of a NetworkStream is limited to a buffer size of 64k. I tried this with a memory stream and I couldn't find any buffer limitations.

Comment: thanks Philipp will check it out. I m using a FileStream. I indeed explored with bigger buffer sizes but there is no guarantee that the Stream would be smaller than the buffer